# How to count people from Multi-column CNN density map?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

In this [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Single-Image-Crowd-Counting-via-Multi-Column-Neural-Zhang-Zhou/427d6d9bc05b07c85fc6b2e52f12132f79a28f6c), they use Multi-column Convolutional Neural Network (MCNN). The output of MCNN is density map (this is a matrix) and from this density map we can count the number of people.

My question are:

1. How does density map matrix look like?
2. What is the formula from which they can count the number of people from density map matrix?

I am new to deep learning so I hope you help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by 'how does density map matrix look like' - the paper has images showing a visual display, are you looking for something different?

Comment: @ReneBt is it a matrix of integer values? Or just 0 and 1